# Airflow plugin operator not running execute method

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create my first airflow plugin, an operator, but I can't get the execute method to run properly.

I've managed to find a good example for how to structure the plugin module and get it imported into airflow.

Here's the structure and code:

```
airflow
├── plugins
  ├── generic_plugin
    ├── __init__.py
    └── operators
        ├── __init__.py
        └── generic_operator.py
```

airflow/plugins/generic_plugin/__init__.py

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from generic_plugin.operators.generic_operator import GenericOperator

class GenericPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "generic_plugin"
    operators = [GenericOperator]
```

airflow/plugins/generic_plugin/operators/generic_operator.py

```
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
import json


class GenericOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self,
                 data,
                 destination_path,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super(GenericOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data
        self.destination_path = destination_path

    def execute(self, context):
        self.dump_data(
            data=self.data,
            destination_path=self.destination_path)

    def dump_data(self, data, destination_path):
        with open(destination_path, 'w') as out_file:
            json.dump(data, out_file)
```

Running this code in the python console, everything is imported correctly, but the execute method doesn't run.

```
from airflow.operators.generic_plugin import GenericOperator

generic_op = GenericOperator(
    task_id='gen_test',
    data={'some_json_data': [
        {'id': 1, 'value': 10}, {'id': 2, 'value': 35}]},
    destination_path='./some_json_data.json')
```

However, the dump_data method works as expected, if I run it manually:

```
generic_op.dump_data(
    data=generic_op.data,
    destination_path=generic_op.destination_path)
```

Am I missing something in how to setup the execute method or isn't the execute method suppose to work like this?

Comment: Is this the whole DAG? Then the call for generic_op might be missing.

Comment: I've tried putting it inside a DAG as well, but it's the same issue. How would you write the DAG?

Comment: OK, I'm just new to this... I put it inside a DAG, restarted the scheduler and the webserver, and ran airflow test, and now it works.